# Get space between an image and text

Tags: html, css

I have an image using style = "float: left; pushed to the left side Then comes a bestimter text currently looks like this now...

[image]

How do I get a bit of space between the image and the text?

```
<div>
<img alt="" src="images/about/uhr.jpg" style="float:left; height:180px; width:180px" />
</div>
<blockquote>
<p></p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</blockquote>
</br>
```

Comment: use `margin-right` in `<img>`

Comment: What have you tried? [margin - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this CSS:

Your HTML CODE:

```
<img alt="" src="images/about/uhr.jpg" class="image-margins" style="float:left; height:180px; width:180px" />
```

YOUR CSS:

```
.image-margins{
    margin: 10px;
}
```

You can remove the style property of image and add it to the css class like:

HTML CODE:

```
<img alt="" src="images/about/uhr.jpg" class="image-margins" /> <!-- LOOT AT THE CLASS ATTRIBUTE -->
```

CSS:

```
.image-margins{
    margin: 10px;
    float:left; 
    height:180px; 
    width:180px;
}
```

Whenever you add `class="image-margins"` attribute to any `img` tag, the above css will be applied to only that element.

**[UPDATED FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/527k6gne/1/)**

Comment: Another question i think you can answer it fast. Im using the css file now but the problem is i got other images and they are no marged too. How can i set the css attribute rule to only 1 specify image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "margin-left" in "blockquote".

Comment: Put the margin-left on the blokquote instead, the p is empty

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I checked it and you are right, it wasn't working as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `margin-right` on the `img` like so:

```
<div>
<img alt="" src="images/about/uhr.jpg" style="float:left; height:180px; width:180px; margin-right:4px;" />
</div>
<blockquote>
<p></p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</blockquote>
</br>
```

This adds space to the right of the img, pushing the text over a bit.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this style

```
<style>
blockquote{
 margin-left:25px;
}
</style>
```

by the way you are starting a p tag with nothing in there so if your styling the p it won't work